# Xml 'Viewer' for MAC - which displays 'without' tags...need only the content

Tags: xml, viewer

I tried a lot in google to find a XML viewer,which only display the content not the meta tags.But i failed to find one.Can any one suggest some free XML viewers for mac OSX?

I want some thing like this...

Input:

```
          <Name> MR.X  </Name>
```

Output:

```
    Name MR.X
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can drop your provided xml file on Safari or Chrome and it will strip tags, but unfortunately there will be no line breaks. Firefox has a nice collapsible tree view. You can add a similar view to Safari with this plugin: http://www.entropy.ch/software/macosx/xmlviewplugin/

If you really need that identical output, I would add a tiny little bit of xslt, which will transform the xml to whatever you want. My favourite tool for doing xslt is http://www.entropy.ch/software/macosx/#testxslt
You can then view the transform in any modern browser, or in TextXSLT.

HTH, J

Comment: http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/objcguide.xml   once check the source xml file...how to display it in readable format like this page on browser?